# Datapager page change event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, datapager

Currently I need to call a method when the user changes the page number of a datapager and moves from one page to another.Can any one one tell me is there any datapager page change event or any work around for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to subscribe to the page change event of the control the datapager is doing the paging for. An instance would be if you are using a gridview then you can subscribe to the gridview **PageIndexChanged** event and put your method call there.

Comment: I believe this is wrong and it is the DataPager itself that has the `PageIndexChanged` event (at least in Silverlight anyway)